# SQL Server Replication, DB Engine & Full-Text and Semantic Extraction status failed

Tags: mysql

I was trying installing MySQL Server 2019 on my computer and I ran into an issue with the installation. I've tried the custom one to get more informations and I have 3 issues.
Here are the errors :

[   Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search   Failed] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/62E0c.png

[   Database Engine Services    Failed] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIT97.png

[   SQL Server Replication  Failed] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNLy1.png

I've already tried unoinstalling everything and reinstalling but the issue persist.
Also in the services.msc, my SQLServer service isn't running and don't want to run.
I am wondering if someone knows what's going and and can help me to solve this issue because I need to for school.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One of the possibilities is to uninstall SQLSERVER and verify that all folders have been removed.

Comment: I've already tried uninstalling and installing several times, I even re-installed Windows on my computer on still get the same issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).